# Entering numbers in masked textbox from right to left with decimal point

Tags: c#, winforms, maskedtextbox

Here is the situation I need addressed:

I have a masked text box that has a mask of `00.0`, I need to be able to enter values in this box with a range from 2 to 20.  The issue is, that I need to enter the values from the right and transfer over the decimal point instead of entering from the right.

For example, at the moment I can type in 160 and it will give me the correct `16.0` value... However if I enter `80`, I get `80`. instead of `8.0`.  I do not want the users to have to enter leading zeros to get the value (`080`).  Is there a way to enter text from the right and have it cross over the decimal point.  This seems like it should be easy, but not having luck so far.

Comment: So if I wanted to enter 20, what would I type? or 2.0?

Comment: Grant, Yes instead of from left to right since the mask is 00.0

Comment: This is Winforms.  If I wanted 20, I would simply enter 200, the result would be 20.0, if I wanted 2.0 I want to be able to just enter 20

Comment: Do you need to do text selections in the input field? If not, roll your own custom control (don't use the standard textbox, but label control(s) perhaps) and handle focus and keyboard events for your control the way you need. If you need text selection then things become very, very complicated...

Comment: elgonzo, I do not need Selections, and shouldnt I be able to handle the focus and keyboard events for the standard controls the same way as custom one?

Comment: With "custom control" i meant inheriting from a standard control and modifiying its behaviour. You could actually use a textbox in readonly mode, i guess. (what i said about labels in my previous comment is obviously slightly nonsensical, sorry ;) ) EDIT: You will still need to do input handling (no "." input) and creating the visible text (including the ".").

Comment: Could I do some kind of comparison function like if the value is over 20, insert a decimal point between the numbers and then update the textbox?

Comment: Yes. You would do this during your handling of key input events. Essentially, when the numerical input has 3 or more digits, create the output text with a ".", otherwise without.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a native way to do that. Your best bet would be to implement a event handler on the TextChanged (or else) action of your textbox and do some modification here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var _value = textBox1.Text.Trim();

    if ((textBox1.Text.Length <= 2)) {
        _value = textBox1.Text.PadLeft(3, "0", c);
    }

    var _changed = _value.Replace(c, "");

    string _split1 = _changed.Substring(0, (_changed.Length - 2));
    string _split2 = _changed.Substring(_split1.Length, 2);
    _value = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0}.{1}", _split1, _split2)).ToString();
    textBox1.Text = _value;
}
```

Comment: The OPs question is tagged with C# and the code that you posted is not in that language.